# jQuery replace <p> tag with line break

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html text like this:

```
<div>
    <p>1111</p>
    <p>2222</p>
    <p>3333</p>
</div>
```

I want to replace `<p>` tag with line break but make all text into `<p>` tag:

```
<div>
    <p>
        1111
        <br/>
        2222
        <br/>
        3333
        <br/>
    </p>
</div>
```

I have tried with `replaceWith` but the result was different from what I want

Comment: try "\n" new line instead "<br/>" line break.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
$("div > p").each(function () {
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).text() + "<br/>");
});
$("div").wrapInner("<p></p>");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vnLnmx0c/

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
var ps = $("#maindiv").find("p");
var par = [];
ps.each(function(index, d){
    par.push($(d).text());
});

var text = par.join("</br>");
//remove all the paragraph dom
$("#maindiv").find("p").remove();
//make aparagraph dom and add the new html text joined by </br>
$("#maindiv").append("p").html(text);
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/uakm1vxx/1/).

Comment: The name of your first variable is misleading as it contains the `<p>` elements inside the `<div>` and not the `<div>` itself. And the part with `par` could be simplified to: `var par = div.map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get();`

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible solution using only javascript.

```js
element = document.getElementById("replace"); //Replace for whatever you want
html = element.innerHTML;
html = html.replace(/<p>(.*)<\/p>/g, "$1<br />"); //$1 here contains all the html between the <p> tags. So you can change this around to what you want it to be, example: <a>$1</a>
element.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="replace">
  <p>1111</p>
  <p>2222</p>
  <p>3333</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a created a fiddle for you. check it

https://jsbin.com/gazefa/edit?html,js,output

```
<button onclick="removePs('target')">Remove Multiple Ps</button>
<div id="target">
    <p>1111</p>
    <p>2222</p>
    <p>3333</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
function removePs(div_id) {
  var html = '<p>';
  $('#' + div_id + ' p').each(function(i, p) {
    html += $(p).html() + '</br>';
  });
  html += '</p>';
  $('#' + div_id).html(html);
}
```